# Finding Jaunt Element not working?

Tags: java, jaunt-api

I'm trying to get a specific element off YouTube (the title of the video).

HTML: http://pastebin.com/cjr2SgNd

Important HTML part:

```
<span id="eow-title" class="watch-title " dir="ltr" title="Latest Agar.io PvP - Create Your Own Server!"></span>
```

I would like to find this: `title="Latest Agar.io PvP - Create Your Own Server!"`

However, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/G7x9FZaa

I'm using Jaunt to get the title.
Code:

```
UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
//troubleshooting
System.out.println("working");

List<String> vid = userAgent.doc.findAttributeValues("<span title>");
System.out.println(vid);
//troubleshooting
System.out.println("working1");
```

Comment: Your stack trace says the exception happened on line 39 of YouConverter.java. Which line of your snippet is that?

Comment: List<String> vid = userAgent.doc.findAttributeValues("<span title>");

Comment: So if userAgent is a new UserAgent object with nothing else done to it, userAgent.doc will be null. Look for some Jaunt tutorials for how to use the UserAgent class.

Comment: OMG LOL, I think I accidently removed that line of code (userAgent.visit)since I had to copy the code and switch it to another class because of workspace issues. Thank you lol